# Can't upload ipa to Testflight: Invalid Bundle

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight, flutter-ios

I have a Flutter app and I need to publish a new release.
The upload used to work with no issues with the previous version of Flutter sdk.

To upload the ipa I run:

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f ./path_to_my.ipa --apiKey *** --apiIssuer ***
```

This is the response

```
*** Error: Error uploading 'path_to_my.ipa'.
*** Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90208 for id ... Asset validation failed (-19208)
 {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Invalid Bundle. The bundle Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework does not support the minimum OS Version specified in the Info.plist. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90208 for id ...";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Asset validation failed";
}
```

This is my env

```
- Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.0, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale it-IT)
- Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
- Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
- Android Studio (version 2021.2)
```

I already tried setting the minimum deployment target to 10.0 everywhere:

- Runner -> Runner -> General -> Deployment info: Target
- Runner -> Runner -> info.plist
- Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist

Any suggestion?

Comment: what is the minimum  os version set in your project for ios

Comment: My MinimumOSVersion is 10.0

Comment: Why 13? Any documentation?

Comment: sorry the minimum version is 11

Comment: Aaah, I missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per flutter doc, Flutter has enforced the minimum plugin version of 11 in flutter version 3.3

For more, read [Flutter 3.3. Release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

I don't if this will work but it worked for me.

But what basically is wrong is App Framework is mismatching the min OS version originally given to it.

Check this Github issue link:  [Here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67492#issuecomment-704991881)

After doing that, run

flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install or pod update

Hope it works fine for you.